# How to Refresh Tkinter Display on a Cycle with No Lag

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, lag

I'm trying to create a simple program to monitor data that displays in a Tkinter window and refreshes itself every second. The method I'm currently using creates an ever-increasing lag in the refresh cycle as the program runs.

This is a super simplified representation of the approach in the form of a counter. While the cycle begins at the intended rate of one second per loop, even after just a few minutes the cycle-time becomes noticeably slower. Any suggestions to eliminate this lag accumulation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

```
from tkinter import *
i=0
root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Clock")
root.configure(background="black")

def Cycle():
    global i
    Label(root, text="------------------------", bg="black", fg="black").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
    Label(root, text = i, bg="black", fg="gray").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
    i += 1
    root.after(1000,Cycle)

root.after(1000,Cycle)    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Stop creating new objects with each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop creating new objects with each call. Instead, only update the parts that change. For the code above it would be updating the 2nd Label's text:

```
from tkinter import *

def Cycle():
    global i
    labels[1]['text'] = i
    i += 1
    root.after(1000,Cycle)

i=0
root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Clock")
root.configure(background="black")
labels = list()
labels.append(Label(root, text="------------------------", bg="black", fg="black"))
labels.append(Label(root, bg="black", fg="gray"))
for j in range(len(labels)):
    labels[j].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
root.after(1000,Cycle)    
root.mainloop()
```